# configuring proxy on webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a json-server running on port 5000 and would like to create a proxy on webpack-dev-server. I tried this in webpack.config.js file

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/assets/',
    proxy: {
      '/': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5000',
        secure: false,
      },
    },
```

but when I try to access items in db.js as `fetch('/items')` it gives me this error message `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` and gives me the error is in `:8080/items:1`. Why?